# Gfi that has 12 2 gauge 20 amp, can i tie a 14 2 gauge in the load terminal for an outlet ans light in my shed

Tags: electrical

I have a gfi with 12 2 20 amp wire, and want to run power to my shed can i tie in 14 2 gauge wire in the load terminal for a outlet and small light

Answer (score 5):

### In this case, there's more than one problem to fix

I suspect you heard "conduit should be buried 6" deep" somewhere, went off to the home store, got the nearest/cheapest conduit you could, and buried it.  (Either that, or someone at the home store told you "conduit should be buried 6" deep.")  Unfortunately for you, that 6" rule only applies to *rigid metal conduit* (RMC) -- the PVC conduit you're using needs to be buried 18" deep, so you'll have to pull the wires out, dig it up, and re-trench it at the deeper depth (and add 12" lengths with couplings at each end to compensate for that).

Once you get the conduit set at the correct burial depth, you can then pull a set of 12AWG THHN/THWNs (black/white/bare) through the conduit.  (Had you gotten the conduit burial right, pulling out the old wire and stuffing new wire down the conduit would have been all that was needed for a fix.)

### For the next bloke: Just use another length of 12/2

You can't do what you want without making the *whole circuit* into a 15A circuit (which requires replacing the breaker with a 15A breaker).  Just get some 12/2 and use that instead.

Comment: Damm its done didnt tie it in tho, it was a pain my brother told me it was 14 2 inside so i didnt look just dug and put conduit down and tied the outlet and light in will it be a problem if i left it

Comment: @Buff35 -- is it a conduit run the whole way?

Comment: First ThreePhaseEel Thank you for repllyings i dug about a 6 in down 20 ft long scheule 40 i wont be usin it often i just wsnted an outlet an light a small light

Comment: @Buff35 -- by "schedule 40" do you mean "schedule 40 PVC"?

Comment: Yes the 14 2 is just for a small chain  pull light and an outlet for my tool charger, thank you agin

Comment: @Buff35 -- so, yes, the conduit is PVC conduit?

Comment: Let me say this is my brothers house , and  at first the outlet was in his hall no gfi, i started the shed part he moved the outlet outside with a gfi on 14 2 i told him he need the 20 amp 12 2 wire he only got 25 ft by that time i was dug in and all set up in the shed i would like to avoid pulling it and redoing it agin

Comment: Yes pvc scheule 40

Comment: GFCI will protect even AWG 16 but breaker with 20A will heat up wire +70’C but 1A bulb will not.  Label it 15A max for next generation and let sleeping dogs lie.